# Why wasn't The Ancient One fighting with her full might?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, we learned that The Ancient One secretly fought

> the Chitauri army in New York (2012).

But, she didn't fight with her full might. She could have simply opened a big portal below the Tesseract's portal to send the incoming Chitauri army into the Sun. She could also open small portals in the trajectory of Leviathan ships to send them into the Sun. Trapping the Chitauri army in the mirror dimension is another option.

Why didn't she fight with her full might?

Comment: Because she's only concerned with protecting the Sanctum. Aliens invading New York is not a concern of the Sorcerers.

Comment: @OrangeDog - Attacking the Chitauri army openly would have made her (and the sanctum) their #1 priority target

Comment: Protection of the timeline. She may have foreseen ahead that this was destined to happen, this protection of the Samctum and no more was the appropriate action to take.

Comment: She wasn't fighting, she was deflecting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the Sorcerers are there to protect against bigger threats than just simple threats like a Chitauri invasion. They are there to protect against the mystical and other dimensions whereas people like the Avengers can handle the clear physical threats as Wong himself states.

> **Doctor Strange:** When do you start telling me what we are?
>
> **Wong:** While heroes like the Avengers protect the world from physical dangers, we sorcerers safeguard it against more mystical threats.
>
> <sub>*Doctor Strange*</sub>

The Sorcerers themselves though do have to protect the Sanctums, and though Wong states below they protect them from *"Other-dimensional beings"* protecting them from immediate physical danger by simply destroying a few things coming nearby doesn't seem like much of a problem.

> **Wong:** Together, the Sanctums generate a protective shield around our world.
>
> **Mordo:** The Sanctums protect the world, and we sorcerers protect the Sanctums.
>
> **Doctor Strange:** From what?
>
> **Wong:** Other-dimensional beings that threaten our universe.
>
> <sub>*Doctor Strange*</sub>

In short she is only protecting the Sanctum because the Sorcerers are only there to protect the Sanctums and threats beyond the physical.